# Activating/Creating/Showing a ViewPart from an internal method

Tags: eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp

Is there an easier way to do this (retaining the ability to use VIEW_VISIBLE, VIEW_ACTIVATE, and VIEW_CREATE)?

```
public class MyView extends ViewPart {
    ...
    public void myMethod() {
        try {
            getSite().getPage().showView(ID, null, IWorkbenchPage.VIEW_VISIBLE);
        } catch (PartInitException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ...
    }
]
```

Comment: Are you within your view when you want to open the other view?  If so, that's the correct way to do it.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to activate an instance of MyView from within MyView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Paul said answers my question